# How to DataBind WPF Slider's Thumb's DragCompleted event

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, slider

I want to bind the DragCompleted event to one of my ViewModel's Command. I tried the following using Blend but it doesn't work:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="412">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Thumb.DragCompleted">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DragCompletedCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Slider>
```

But this doesn't work. When I use the normal binding of event to code behind, it works:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" Thumb.DragCompleted="slider_DragCompleted"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="412"></Slider>
```

I tried searching but strangely couldn't find answer to this.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I think I've run into this in the past. Because Thumb.DragCompleted is not actually a part of Slider (it is attached to slider), This Interaction trigger does not respond to it. But if you edit copy of the slider's template, you can the paste your interaction trigger straight to the Thumb and this will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an attached property for this which can look like:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyTestApplication
{
    internal class SliderExtension
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DragCompletedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DragCompletedCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(SliderExtension),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand), OnDragCompletedCommandChanged));

        private static void OnDragCompletedCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Slider slider = d as Slider;
            if (slider == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (e.NewValue is ICommand)
            {
                slider.Loaded += SliderOnLoaded;
            }
        }

        private static void SliderOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Slider slider = sender as Slider;
            if (slider == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            slider.Loaded -= SliderOnLoaded;

            Track track = slider.Template.FindName("PART_Track", slider) as Track;
            if (track == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            track.Thumb.DragCompleted += (dragCompletedSender, dragCompletedArgs) =>
            {
                ICommand command = GetDragCompletedCommand(slider);
                command.Execute(null);
            };
        }

        public static void SetDragCompletedCommand(DependencyObject element, ICommand value)
        {
            element.SetValue(DragCompletedCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static ICommand GetDragCompletedCommand(DependencyObject element)
        {
            return (ICommand)element.GetValue(DragCompletedCommandProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

And your Slider-Definition then looks like:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="412" 
        extensions:SliderExtension.DragCompletedCommand="{Binding SlideCompletedCommand}"/>
```

`extensions` is the namespace where your attached property is located.

And in your ViewModel you have an `ICommand`-Property called SlideCompletedCommand, which can look like:

```
private ICommand slideCompletedCommand;
public ICommand SlideCompletedCommand
{
    get { return slideCompletedCommand ?? (slideCompletedCommand = new RelayCommand(p => SlideCompleted())); }
}

private void SlideCompleted()
{
    // Your slide-completed-code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But as the Thumb is part of slider, they should have provided a way to access it via XAML.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using the code behind to access the ViewModel.

In xaml:

```
<Slider Thumb.DragCompleted="OnThumbDragCompleted"/>
```

In code-behind (considering that the DataContext of the view is ViewModel):

```
private void OnThumbDragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).DragCompleted();
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
public void DragCompleted()
{
    // event processing
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question given they look specifically for a binding. Moreover, OP's question already mentions this way to use the event