# Binding a Slider Command in WPF, MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, slider

I have a slider in XAML, and I would like to bind the "Thumb.DragCompleted" event handler to a command that I have defined in the ViewModel. My code is as follows:

```
            <Slider Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Maximum="100" TickFrequency="100"
                    Value="{Binding ExposureTime}" Thumb.DragCompleted="SliderDragCompleted">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Thumb.DragCompleted">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction x:Name="SliderCompleted" Command="{Binding SetExposureCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                
            </Slider>
```

And here is the function in my viewModel:

```
public ICommand SetExposureCommand => _setExposure ?? (_setExposure = new CommonCore.GuiControls.Commands.RelayCommand(SetExposure));

   public void SexExposure()
   {
      vimbaCamera.SetExposure(ExposureTime);
   }
```

The function is never called, though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [How to DataBind WPF Slider's Thumb's DragCompleted event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40848343/18990321)

Comment: @johann yes, i tried that one, but it didn't work for me. The extended property was not recognized.

Comment: did you add the extensions namespace (`xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.Extensions"`) at the top of your xaml file?

Answer (score 1):

`Thumb.DragCompleted` is an attached event and the `EventTrigger` that you are using doesn't support attached events.

You will either have to implement your own [custom event trigger](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-invoking-command-on-attached-event.html) or you could simply invoke the command from your `SliderDragCompleted` event handler:

```
private void SliderDragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    SetExposureCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

This doesn't break the MVVM pattern since you are invoking the very same command from the very same view compared to if you have used an interaction trigger in the XAML markup. MVVM isn't about eliminating code from the view - it's about separation of concerns.